# How to redefine the \emph command in Beamer?

Tags: macros, beamer, emphasis

I am using the Beamer class and would like to redefine `\emph` to use `\bfseries` instead of `\itshape`. I have tried the following command:

```
\renewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\bfseries}#1}}
```

but I get the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \beamerx@\emph already defined.
          Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

I cannot understand: Why is it a problem that `\emph` already is defined when I am using `\renewcommand`?

Comment: The code has two problems: a) spurious `<>`; b) inconsistent parameter number (1 declared, 2 used). Perhaps you could comment on what is the new `\emph` supposed to do — this would make things clearer.

Comment: The `<>` is not spurious. According to the beamer manual (page 86 in version 3.10), you can redefine an existing command by `\renewcomamnd<>\cmd[1]{...}`. The second parameter stores the overlay specification.

Comment: @Michael: My bad. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the code, I'd say that this was a bug.  Beamer defines a wrapper around the `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` environments which step in when they are called with a following `<>`.  But the new `\renewcommand` seems to do the following:

1. Save the original definition
2. Call the modified `\newcommand`

Now the modified `\newcommand` calls internally calls the original `\newcommand` but what it *ought* to do here is now call the original `\renewcommand`.  (The error message, by the way, is because the original `\newcommand` is not called on the command specified, in this case `\emph`, but again there's a level of wrapping on top to deal with the overlay stuff.)

So, to fix this:

1. Email the beamer maintainers informing them that you think you've found a bug.
2. You *could* use the following code to temporarily fix this problem.  Basically, I've just copied out the code that handles `\newcommand` and replace "new" by "renew" at all instances, *however*
3. Email the beamer maintainers to say that fixing this bug reveals one or two more!  When I use the above code then I get a few errors about commands not being defined.  My interpretation of this is that beamer does a few redefinitions (at the `\begin{document}` time) using `\renewcommand`.  With the old version, if the command-to-be-redefined is *not* currently defined then this goes through just fine.  However, with the new version then if the command-to-be-redefined is not currently defined then this produces errors!  (The guilty commands are `\includegraphics` and `\pgfuseimage`.)

Anyway, here's the fix.  Use at your own risk:

```
\makeatletter
\def\renewcommand{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@renewcom}{\beamer@origrenewcommand}}
\def\beamer@renewcom<>{\@star@or@long\beamer@renew@command}
\def\beamer@renew@command#1{\@ifnextchar[{\beamer@@renewcom{#1}}{\beamer@renewcomnoopt
{#1}{0}}}
\def\beamer@@renewcom#1[#2]{\@ifnextchar[{\beamer@renewcomopt{#1}{#2}}{\beamer@renewcomnoopt{#1}{#2}}}
\long\def\beamer@renewcomnoopt#1#2#3{%
  \ifnum#2=0\relax%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@sortzero\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}}%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@sort\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}{#2}}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@argscount=#2\relax%
  \advance\beamer@argscount by 1\relax%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname[\beamer@argscount]{#3}%
}
\long\def\beamer@renewcomopt#1#2[#3]#4{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@presort\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}{#2}{#3}}%
  \beamer@argscount=#2\relax%
  \advance\beamer@argscount by 1\relax%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname[\beamer@argscount]{#4}%
}
\makeatother
```

(**Added in edit**): I made a mistake in the above code: it doesn't save the original version of the command which the beamer version of `\renewcommand` does.  Also, due to the conflicts, I thought that actually it would be better to define a command `\myrenewcommand` which does the command.  So the code below may be better.  It's probably still nowhere near perfect - for example, I don't know if the `\@star@or@long` is appropriate for `\renewcommand`s.

Anyway, here's version 2 wrapped up in a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13726/86

\makeatletter
\def\myrenewcommand{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@myrenewcom}{\beamer@origrenewcommand}}
\def\beamer@myrenewcom<>{\@star@or@long\beamer@myrenew@command}
\def\beamer@myrenew@command#1{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\beamer@name\expandafter{\csname @orig\string#1\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\let\beamer@name=#1\relax%
\@ifnextchar[{\beamer@@myrenewcom{#1}}{\beamer@myrenewcomnoopt
{#1}{0}}}
\def\beamer@@myrenewcom#1[#2]{\@ifnextchar[{\beamer@myrenewcomopt{#1}{#2}}{\beamer@myrenewcomnoopt{#1}{#2}}}
\long\def\beamer@myrenewcomnoopt#1#2#3{%
  \ifnum#2=0\relax%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@sortzero\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}}%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@sort\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}{#2}}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@argscount=#2\relax%
  \advance\beamer@argscount by 1\relax%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname[\beamer@argscount]{#3}%
}
\long\def\beamer@myrenewcomopt#1#2[#3]#4{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@presort\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}{#2}{#3}}%
  \beamer@argscount=#2\relax%
  \advance\beamer@argscount by 1\relax%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname[\beamer@argscount]{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\myrenewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\bfseries}#1}}

\newcommand<>{\test}[1]{{\only#2{\bfseries}#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some \emph{emphasised} text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have reported the bug: https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/119/problem-when-redefining-commands-like-emph

Comment: @Ulrik: Good!  Don't forget to report back if you get confirmation or anything else significant.

Comment: @Andrew: Amongst other things, I _am_ one of the `beamer` maintainers. This does look wrong to me - expect the patch to be added later today.

Comment: @Joseph: Yippee-do!  I had a hazy recollection that you were somehow involved, but couldn't remember for sure.  I'll be interested to see your patch and see what the most _efficient_ way of doing this is (and why I was getting those weird things with `\includegraphics` as I couldn't see why they were being generated when I dug deeper).

Comment: @Andrew: One issue with `beamer` is that Till's code is rather awkward to follow/alter! So the major approach is 'do not alter too much'.

Comment: @Andrew: This is a case in point - if you try to use the same definition for `\renewcommand` as for `\newcommand` all hell breaks loose! I have a fix for the matter in hand - it will be in the repo in a second, but I need Vedran to do a release (he's in charge of `beamer`).

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, I quickly gave up the chase of which uses of `\renewcommand` were legitimate and which were a bit .. dubious.

Comment: @Andrew. One of the reasons fixes for `beamer` are quite slow at the moment (at least for me) is that while Till does a great job for the _user_, the internals are 'interesting' (try reading `pgf`!).

Comment: This was eventually fixed in 2017 AFAICT (this patch is for `renewenvironment` though): https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/4c65e1663794d4172dc8cd73ade660d566c9e5e8 Debian stretch (TexLive 2016) does not contain it, but buster (TL2018) does.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is have `\emph` embolden its text, you could do:

```
\let\emph\textbf
```

Each macro is overlay-specification aware and has the same “signature.”  So just alias one for the other.