# Biblatex: Removing underlining of journal title and enabling line break of it

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, journal

I'd like to use authoryear-comp for my bibliography. However, I'd like to suppress underlining the journal title that seems to be set default.

Also, I got the problem that a line break is not inserted into the journal title, so that the title extends beyond the border. Is there a way to change this?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxnames=1, doi=false, url=false, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\bibliography{LitThesis}

\begin{document}
Here is my reference \parencite{Hummelen1997}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Bibtex code:

```
@ARTICLE{Hummelen1997,
author = {the author},
title = {the title},
journal = {Chemistry},
year = {1997},
volume = {3},
pages = {1489--1493},
number = {9},
month = {09}
}
```

So concerning the problem with the month I tried to do the following:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxnames=1, doi=false, url=false, month=false, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

But I get an error because "month" is not recognized as a value. Is there a way to suppress showing the month in the bibliography?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: @Anja: It sounds as if you are loading a package which redefined `\emph` to underline. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You can try \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\isdot}
but an example might be needed. I hav not used this style in a while but I don't remember anything beeing underlined

Comment: @ Joseph: While creating an MWE I noticed that indeed I had the ulem-package that was causing this problem. Upon removal of the package both problems were solved. Thank you!

Comment: Just one more question - how can I suppress the month in the bibliographye? "month = false" seems not to work (it gives me an error).

Comment: @Anja: You can load the package `ulem` with the option `normalem`

Comment: @Anja: Please make a minimal example. See the comment of Joseph

Comment: @ Marco: Thanks for the advice with ulem! Concerning the month, I added an MWE.

Comment: @Anja: That would be better as a separate question, which Thorsten can then answer. (The idea on the site is that each question should be independent.)

Comment: @Joseph: I am sorry, I didn't know that as I'm new here. I guess there is no point now to open a new question, but I'll keep that in mind for the future!

Comment: This is long past, but I found `microtype` also modifies working of `biblatex/biber`.  I had a journal title that started in the right margin.  There is probably an option in `microtype` to make sure that it does not do that, but at this stage I dont't have the time to search for that.

Answer (score 6):

How to hide `month` in the bibliography:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxnames=1, doi=false, url=false, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\bibliography{LitThesis}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{month}%
}
\begin{document}
Here is my reference \parencite{Hummelen1997}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

To suppress underlining the journal title (and allow line breaks):

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\emph#1{\ifmmode\nfss@text{\em #1}\else\hmode@bgroup\text@command{#1}\em\check@icl #1\check@icr\expandafter\egroup\fi}
\makeatother
```

You may check [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13726/how-to-redefine-the-emph-command-in-beamer?rq=1) for `\emph` redefinition in `beamer`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps you can extend your answer by providing a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to the OP.

Comment: Well this works for me, thanks! But is there no easier solution for this? For example a package option would be nice. Why is biber underlining the journal title by standard?

Comment: @tc88: Afaik, biber is not underlining the journal title, rather biber is using \emph{...}.  But the ulem package apparently defines \emph to be underline; passing the normalem option when loading ulem (as suggested by Marco Daniel in a comment up higher) prevents this, and is an easier and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

Although the MWE in the question does not show it, the comments indicate that in the real document the `ulem` package was used. This causes underlining of text that is displayed with `\emph`, which is used for journal titles. To prevent underlining the following package option can be used:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```