# Redefine block environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, macros, environments

I'm trying to redefine the `block` environment in `beamer` so that the `itemize`/`enumerate` bullets follow the color of `block title` instead of `structure`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\renewenvironment<>{block}[1]{%
    \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \mode<presentation>{%
        \setbeamercolor{local structure}{use=block title,%
           fg=block title.bg}}%
      \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par%
      \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
    \end{actionenv}}
```

But this immediately throws the error

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command \beamerx@\block already defined.
```

This seems very similar to the problem discussed at: [How to redefine the \emph command in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13726/how-to-redefine-the-emph-command-in-beamer)

The aforementioned thread culminated in the discovery of a bug in beamer which was patched 4 years ago, and I'm wondering if this might be a similar bug in beamer's renewenvironment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be also a similar bug with `\newenvironment` in `beamer`. The problem is the same mentioned by Loop Space in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13727/3954) to [How to redefine the \emph command in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13726/3954). The problem seems to be the same mentioned in the linked answer and the "solution" is similar.

Below, I replaced `\newcommand` by `\renewcommand` in two places in the definition of `\beamer@newenvnoopt` (original definition in the file `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`); the places were the change were made were marked `%<- here`.

Please, use at your own risk.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% ``Fix'' for possible bug
\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@newenvnoopt#1#2#3#4{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter<\expandafter>\csname#1\endcsname[#2]{#3}%<- here
  \expandafter\long\expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{#4}%
}
\long\def\beamer@newenvopt#1#2[#3]#4#5{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter<\expandafter>\csname#1\endcsname[#2][#3]{#4}%<- here
  \expandafter\long\expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{#5}%
}
\makeatother

\renewenvironment<>{block}[1]{%
    \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \mode<presentation>{%
        \setbeamercolor{local structure}{use=block title,%
           fg=block title.bg}}%
      \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par%
      \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
    \end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{A test new block}
test
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've contacted one of the `beamer` maintainers about this.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the answer would be something similar to this, but my TeX wizard level wasn't quite high enough. I have opened a bug report with your proposed fix on the development repository: https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issues/322/renewenvironment-throws-errors

Comment: This was eventually fixed in 2017 AFAICT: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/4c65e1663794d4172dc8cd73ade660d566c9e5e8 Debian stretch (TexLive 2016) does not contain it, but buster (TL2018) does.

Comment: This solution does not work if you want to wrap/reuse the old block definition. If you try to do so (by using `\originalblock` & `\endoriginalblock` or with `\LetLtxMacro` manually) you end up with an endless loop.