# Change Placement of In-Frame Beamer Notes - [item]-Notes NOT at End of Page

Tags: beamer, notes

Currently, (and this is even mentioned in the current [Beamer User Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), Chapter 19), in-frame notes are ordered such that those notes that used the "[item]" option are all bunched up at the end of the subject note page.

**Is there a relatively painless way to change this so that you can list said "[item]" notes, say, in the middle of the notes page?**

Here is a MWE to show what I'm looking for:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    This is boring.
    \note{I want this to be line 1\par}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 2}
    \note{I want this to be line 3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output (notes page) of this code is:

[image: **enter image description here**]

***WHAT FINALLY WORKED FOR ME:***

*Please see the selected answer below, plus the comments attached to same, for the explanation behind the following code.  Also note that the indentation problem (as per ted_kingdom's comment below said selected answer) still exists.*

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\def\myrenewcommand{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@myrenewcom}{\beamer@origrenewcommand}}
\def\beamer@myrenewcom<>{\@star@or@long\beamer@myrenew@command}
\def\beamer@myrenew@command#1{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\beamer@name\expandafter{\csname @orig\string#1\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\let\beamer@name=#1\relax%
\@ifnextchar[{\beamer@@myrenewcom{#1}}{\beamer@myrenewcomnoopt
{#1}{0}}}
\def\beamer@@myrenewcom#1[#2]{\@ifnextchar[{\beamer@myrenewcomopt{#1}{#2}}{\beamer@myrenewcomnoopt{#1}{#2}}}
\long\def\beamer@myrenewcomnoopt#1#2#3{%
  \ifnum#2=0\relax%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@sortzero\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}}%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@sort\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}{#2}}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@argscount=#2\relax%
  \advance\beamer@argscount by 1\relax%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname[\beamer@argscount]{#3}%
}
\long\def\beamer@myrenewcomopt#1#2[#3]#4{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter\beamer@presort\expandafter{\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname}{#2}{#3}}%
  \beamer@argscount=#2\relax%
  \advance\beamer@argscount by 1\relax%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname beamerx@\string#1\endcsname[\beamer@argscount]{#4}%
}


\makeatletter
\myrenewcommand<>{\beamer@inframenote}[2][]{%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \only#3{%
      \def\beamer@temp{#1}%
      \ifx\beamer@temp\beamer@itemtext%
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\beamer@notes%
        \expandafter{\beamer@notes\par\hskip30pt$\bullet$\hskip10pt#2\par}%
      \else
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\beamer@notes%
         \expandafter{\beamer@notes#2\par}
      \fi%
    }%
  \fi%
  }

\begin{frame}
    This is boring.
    \note{I want this to be line 1}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 2}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 3}
    \note{I want this to be line 4}
    \note{I want this to be line 5}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 6}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 7}
    \note{I want this to be line 8}
    \note{I want this to be line 9}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 10}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minimal working example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>{\beamer@inframenote}[2][]{%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \only#3{%
      \def\beamer@temp{#1}%
      \ifx\beamer@temp\beamer@itemtext%
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\beamer@notes%
        \expandafter{\beamer@notes\par\hskip30pt$\bullet$\hskip10pt#2\par}%
      \else
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\beamer@notes%
          \expandafter{\beamer@notes#2}%
      \fi%
    }%
  \fi%
  }

\begin{frame}
    This is boring.
    \note{I want this to be line 1}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 2}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 3}
    \note{I want this to be line 4}
    \note{I want this to be line 5}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 6}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 7}
    \note{I want this to be line 8}
    \note{I want this to be line 9}
    \note[item]{I want this to be line 10}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that it works. However, it breaks text indentation of the itemised text spanned across multiple lines.

Comment: @ted_kingdom Maybe we can fix it by `\parshape` or `\hangindent` or whatsoever... I have little idea about the TeX core.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you for answering!

Comment: This does not work for me.  I get the following error message: `! LaTeX Error: Command \beamerx@\beamer@inframenote already defined.`     `Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`  I get this result using versions `3.07-2` and `3-10.2` of Beamer...

Comment: @Digger It seems related to [a known, solved bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13726/). Maybe ....... update?

Comment: @Symbol1 I used version 2 of Loop Space's code (from the link in your above comment), which _did_ get me to the output of your above MWE.  However, I must point out that said MWE is still not the solution I was seeking, as it runs lines 4 and 5, and lines 8 and 9, together...

Comment: @Digger Lines 4 and 5 are together because there is not `\par` at the end of line 4. In your MWE there does exist a `\par`. So what do you want? You want to control this manually or automatically? For the later, replace the line `\expandafter{\beamer@notes#2}` by `\expandafter{\beamer@notes#2\par}`.

Comment: @Symbol1, although I could not get manual control to work correctly, your line replacement (in the above comment) for automatic operation worked as desired.

Comment: FYI, my original question contains a MWE that shows the code that ultimately ended up working for me.